# "Report-To" HTTP header implementation for GAE Standard

Tags: google-cloud-platform, http-headers, google-app-engine, yaml, google-app-engine-standard

I'm attempting to add a "Report-To:" HTTP header to our App Engine's app.yaml configuration file for integration with https://report-uri.com (based on the Reporting API [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/09/reportingapi), [here](https://github.com/w3c/reporting/blob/master/EXPLAINER.md), and [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/reporting/#examples)) but when I push the changes to the repository, Cloud Build fails and returns the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) An error occurred while parsing file: [/workspace/app.yaml]

in "/workspace/app.yaml", line 21, column 27
ERROR
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud" failed: exit status 1
```

Line 21 of the app.yaml corresponds to the new header:

```
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  http_headers:
    Report-To: {"group":"default","max_age":31536000,"endpoints":[{"url":"https://*REDACTED*.report-uri.com/a/d/g"}],"include_subdomains":true}
```

I've tried different iterations of the header including the following:

```
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: www/index.html
  upload: www/index.html
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
  http_headers:
    Report-To: {"max_age":31536000, "url":"https://*REDACTED*.report-uri.com/a/d/g"}
```

This is the only line item that throws an error on deployment. If removed, the new version goes live. Is it because the header is not supported on App Engine or a mistake in our syntax? Let me know if there are any additional steps to take.

Comment: Wrap the value in single quotes.

Comment: Thanks womble, the quotes were the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YAML strings with special characters must be quoted. Wrap the string in single quotes, and that should take care of everything.